# Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I know this has been answered previously, but none of those solutions are working for me. Can some one please help me with the error below?

I am getting an error using **Ng-Repeat** with **Custom filters** when I am not getting an Array.

Can anyone help me to comeup with controller to use ng-repeat which will handle for both JSONObject and JSONArray

HTML Code

```
<td class="features" ng-show="list.Body.WorkOrder.OrderStatus.length > 0">
<span ng-repeat="indi in list.Body.Services.ServiceChanges.ServiceDisconnects.Service | filterWithOr:{_serviceID:['SS001','ST099','SS018']} ">{{indi._serviceID}},{{indi.EPCServiceDef.EPCProduct._pn}}<br></span>
</td>
```

**Error Will Produce when I have ServiceDisconnects section as below**

```
 "ServiceDisconnects": {
  "Service": {
    "-serviceID": "ST099",
    "ServiceChangeActivity": "Disconnect",
    "TelephoneNumbers": {
      "TN": "                    "
    },
    "Rate": "0.00",
    "Desc": "Xhnoecosvr",
    "Count": "0",
    "LOB": "Other",
    "PackageCode": "ST099   ",
    "EPCServiceDef": {
      "EPCProduct": {
        "-pn": "10400138",
        "Name": "EcoSaver Opt-Out Tracking",
        "LongDescription": "NO ECOSAVER TRACKING",
        "Type": "Feature",
        "LOB": "Video"
      }
    },
    "CSGServiceIdentifier": "5"
  }
}
```

But the same thing will work when the ServiceDisconnects section has multiple Service Arrays.

Here is the Custom Filter

```
app.filter('filterWithOr', function($filter) {
    var comparator = function(actual, expected) {
        if (angular.isUndefined(actual)) {
            // No substring matching against `undefined`
            return false;
        }
        if ((actual === null) || (expected === null)) {
            // No substring matching against `null`; only match against `null`
            return actual === expected;
        }
        if ((angular.isObject(expected) && !angular.isArray(expected)) || (angular.isObject(actual) && !hasCustomToString(actual))) {
            // Should not compare primitives against objects, unless they have custom `toString` method
            return false;
        }

        actual = angular.lowercase('' + actual);
        if (angular.isArray(expected)) {
            var match = false;
            expected.forEach(function(e) {
                e = angular.lowercase('' + e);
                if (actual.indexOf(e) !== -1) {
                    match = true;
                }
            });
            return match;
        } else {
            expected = angular.lowercase('' + expected);
            return actual.indexOf(expected) !== -1;
        }
    };
    return function(campaigns, filters) {
        return $filter('filter')(campaigns, filters, comparator);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're only showing a subset of the `json` in your post?

Your `Service` property in your json is an object, not an array. To iterate over object properties, you'll need to use the other form of `ng-repeat` which is:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj"></div>
```

You're also going to want to update your `filterWithOr` filter to reflect those changes since you're not dealing with arrays.

Couple of things to note according to the [ng-repeat Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) with using `(key, value)`

> The JavaScript specification does not define the order of keys
>   returned for an object, so Angular relies on the order returned by the
>   browser when running for key in myObj. Browsers generally follow the
>   strategy of providing keys in the order in which they were defined,
>   although there are exceptions when keys are deleted and reinstated.
>   See the MDN page on delete for more info.
>
> ngRepeat will silently ignore object keys starting with $, because
>   it's a prefix used by Angular for public ($) and private ($$)
>   properties.
>
> The built-in filters orderBy and filter do not work with objects, and
>   will throw an error if used with one.

Comment: F I agree with answer but is there any solution where i can controller which will help me to use ng-repeat for both JSONObject and JSONArray since my JSON data some times comes as array and sometime as Object